# Accessing Enovia's python interface from Excel / VBA?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings, vba

We are using software called Enovia.

I would like to query Enovia from inside Excel / VBA.

After some search, Enovia seems to have a programming interface called Abaqus.

http://www.3ds.com/products-services/simulia/services/training-courses/course-descriptions/introduction-to-the-abaqus-scripting-interface/

I would like to access this interface in VBA directly but I didn't find anything to that effect.

I found two projects that might allow Excel/VBA to talk to python components or at least to python scripts.

They are as follows

Python For Excel
http://opentradingsystem.com/PythonForExcel/main.html

And the discontinued excelpython
github.com/ericremoreynolds/excelpython
which became integrated in xlwings
xlwings.org

I am not familiar with python nor these two projects. I'm not sure if they will allow me to do what I want.

I'm ok with learning some python to do this but my main program and user interface is in excel.

I figure I could make some simple python scripts then call them through the python interpreter from excel with shellexecute but that is not a very elegant solution I think.

Any advice welcomed

thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Enovia uses the **`MQL`** language for scripting. There are some guides available, such as http://emdros.org/MQL-Programmers-Guide.pdf

I would recommend some training such as http://www.techniatranscat.com/services/education/mql-and-tcl-intro as this doesnt seem to be a very common language.

Not to be confused with the financial trading language `MQL4/MQL5` from MetaQuotes Software Corp.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. Is the the same TCL as "Tool Command Language" ? I did some tiny bit of tcl/tk about 10 years ago, what luck !   I hope I can find a way to interface this MQL/TCL from VBA, so I can do the heavy lifting in a language I'm fluent in !   Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

ENOVIA does not have a Python programming interface.

[Abaqus](http://www.3ds.com/products-services/simulia/products/abaqus/) is a FEA  simulation software which can be scripted with its own Python programming interface.

[ENOVIA](http://www.3ds.com/products-services/enovia/products/v5/latest-release/) though, is a PLM software solution. They are different software for completely different applications. As programming interfaces you may look at maybe [this](http://www.3ds.com/products-services/enovia/products/enovia-v5/vplm/all-products/domain/CAA_RADE-1/)

In short, you may need to contact your Dassault Systemes local support team to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks !
So I was wrong about abaqus, I assume that was it since it is the first result to a "enovia scripting" search ! I figure they used the same scripting engine in all their products.

I also found something called SmarTeam but I'm having trouble finding much about it, like does it even still exist. It seems to be an internal scripting language for the old V5 enovia.

Answer (score 0):

Using tcl and mql you can solve the problem

[TCL](https://tcl.tk/) | 
[MQL](http://emdros.org/MQL-Programmers-Guide.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, I've heard that there is a TCL/MQL interface somewhere, but how do you access it ? I find enovia has a very confused user interface and I can't really find how to access this programming interface. Perhaps it is only available to server admins ?

Comment: you can work on mql.exe.


You query data with mql query,You can use java or tcl to play data.


You need to understand the attributes, properties and relationship in queries.

Comment: There is no interface with as much as I know. You can use netbeans or eclips to develop Java

Comment: You mean, using eclipse rcp to make an http client and control enovia through it's web interface ?

Answer (score 0):

Latest Enovia version 3DEXPERIENCE support Rest based webservices. you can create a rest API in enovia and can call rest service using vb script in excel.

[3DEXPERIENCE Enovia Rest webservice Framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkBPQ.png)

Comment: Please read [answer]. This looks a _lot_ like spam and I almost flagged it as such.

Comment: Thanks, How can I test if my version of enovia has this feature and that it is enabled ? Could you post a VBA function that does the simplest possible query to this system. The software I have is called "3Dexperience | ENOVIA collaboration and approvals" "3DEXPERIENCE R2014x 2014 Dassault Systèmes"

Answer (score 0):

Above mentioned Rest framework may not be available with 2014X version. You have to try SOAP based service or JAX-RS.

**Option 1**

Enovia is java based application and doesn't support VBA ADK to directly work with backend data. However webservice can be used communicate between applications of different platforms or managed by different programming ADK.

For this you need to create your own service (REST/SOAP).  For this you will need server access and first you have to write some java code (Rest/SOAP service) and update the class/jar into 2014 server (tomcat).
Then you can make use of that service in to your vba function.
Again you have to decide the kind of data whether xml or json it is separate topic.

**Option 2**

As I told earlier Enovia is Java based application, It provides JAVA ADK to extend its functionality.

Sample code shows how you can get the context and work with Enovia ADK.

```
matrix.db.Context ctx = new matrix.db.Context("http://myserver-nocas:8080/enovia");
ctx.setUser("Test Everything");
ctx.setPassword("");
ctx.connect();
System.out.println("Is context set "+ctx.isConnected());
```

As you mentioned you are currently using 3DEXPERIENCE then 3DPassport might block above URL method connection, So you need to pass NO-CAS URL.

You can get the context by running above java code from your local eclipse.  Using this ADK you can also call MQL queries and work seamlessly.

```
import com.matrixone.apps.domain.util.MqlUtil;
String strPartFamily  = MqlUtil.mqlCommand(ctx,"temp query bus Part * * select attribute[Length]");
```

But again this is java based solution and not VBA.

Finally 3DEXPERIENCE provides MQL console in server, to play around with all the data using SQL like queries in more developer friendly manner. Enovia also provides web based MQL console but you need to have some license for that (Administrator should be having access).

Answer (score 0):

Use TCL to go through Excel sheet, it is very easy. Use "/t" to separate data.